# Hibernate DB record update, Code running but DB is not updated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to coding, but I am enjoying the learning experience. I am stuck tho and would love some help. 
I am trying to write a simple method to topup a user balance, the topup method code below, once the amount is updated write it to the DB, I am using Mysql.

The code is compiling and I am getting expected results in memory, the balance is updated, however it is not written to the DB, and no errors. I am suspecting something is wrong with my implementation of the update query. I set the balance, I start trans, update, flush, end trans, not sure if this is the right way. Appreciate some directions.

```
public void Topup(BigDecimal amount)
{
    System.out.println("entering topup method");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    if (balance!=null)
    {
    balance = balance.add(amount);

    }

    else {
        balance = balance.ZERO ;
        balance = balance.add(amount);
    }

    setBalance(balance);

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    em.createQuery("update Balance set balance = balance where 
    idsender=idsender")
    .executeUpdate();

    em.flush();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same constant string, "update Balance set balance = balance where idsender=idsender" all the time.

You need to to insert your variables into the string, something like

```
"update Balance set balance = " + balance + "where idsender = " + someId
```

Of course you need to convert balance to a string and also replace someId with a proper value.